# Remove hover css on WooCommerce products to make it single click

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, hover

I need help with a hover issue on my website when using iOS.

https://www.bepierced.com/shop

On iOS it takes 2 clicks to get to the product as the first click activates the hover effect. I didn't design the website so I am a bit lost on how to remove this effect only on mobile could anyone give me some help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it, is relocating the CSS inside this rule: `@supports not (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch)`

Like so:

```
@supports not (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
   .post_item .post_featured:hover .mask,
   .post_item .post_featured:hover .icons {
      opacity: 1;
   }
}
```

Now, this hover will only be applied to non-iOS devices.

If you for any reason would like to only apply this to an iPhone, you can also add a @media rule to target a specific screen width for instance.

- Read more about the `@supports not` rule [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)
- Read more about the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` CSS property and why you can target iOS devices with it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the issue comes from the `.icons` element (which contains a link). I'd recommend to add `display: none` for touch devices, as there is a link wrapping the image (so you don't need `.icons` and `.mask` on touch device)

Comment: Could you advise where I would put this code just so I can test?

Comment: @MichaelBrowne you should edit your CSS file. :)

Comment: @JeroenW sorry I have very basic knowledge could you guide me a bit thanks again for your help

Comment: @MichaelBrowne learn more about how to find your Wordpress theme's CSS file here: https://wordpress.com/support/custom-design/how-to-find-your-themes-css/